# How to define a custom build setting?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want my users to be able to define a value in their `project/` definition that will be used as a URL for fetching a remote configuration file, which an sbt plugin will in turn use. I can't figure out how to define such a value though. When I try to add it to `build.sbt` I get this error:

```
/Users/2rs2ts/src/my-cool-plugin/build.sbt:74: error: not found: value myConfigUrl
myConfigUrl := "http://mycoolwebsite.com/config.xml"
^
[error] Type error in expression
```

Probably because it's not part of `Keys`. But I don't know how I'm supposed to add something like this. Even after that point, I don't know how to access the setting in my plugin's Scala source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `settingKey` macro to define the `myConfigUrl` key.

A sample `build.sbt` could be as follows:

```
lazy val myConfigUrl = settingKey[String]("URL for fetching a remote configuration file")

myConfigUrl := "http://mycoolwebsite.com/config.xml"
```

A sample session:

```
➜  my-cool-plugin  xsbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to my-cool-plugin (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/my-cool-plugin/)
> show myConfigUrl
[info] http://mycoolwebsite.com/config.xml
```

Given [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214408/how-to-define-a-custom-build-setting/25218522?noredirect=1#comment39335969_25218522) where the OP asked:

> How can I refer to this in my project code now? I want to be able to
>   access the value I assigned to myConfigUrl in one of my .scala files,
>   not related to the build process.

the key should be defined in `build.scala` build object as no keys in `*.sbt` files are visible in `project/*.scala` files.

Here is a sample `project/build.scala` build definition with the key:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object build extends Build {
  lazy val myConfigUrl = settingKey[String]("URL for fetching a remote configuration file")

  lazy val mySettings = inConfig(Compile) { Seq(
    myConfigUrl := "http://mycoolwebsite.com/config.xml"
  )}

}
```

With the Scala build, change `build.sbt` to be as follows:

```
mySettings
```

You could do it since every build file is automatically imported in `*.sbt` files and hence accessing vals becomes simple like that. To have the settings - the single `myConfigUrl` key - available in the project you need to add the `Seq[Setting]` val.

Do `reload` and the key should be available as if it was before:

```
> show myConfigUrl
[info] http://mycoolwebsite.com/config.xml
```

Given [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214408/how-to-define-a-custom-build-setting/25218522#comment39343496_25218522):

> I'm particularly interested in a way to let end users of
>   my-cool-plugin define their own myConfigUrl which will be used instead
>   of the default one in my-cool-plugin's build.sbt

it's clear on the intent of the key. This is a key of the plugin so just add `sbtPlugin := true` to the build, `publishLocal` the project and use `addSbtPlugin` to declare a `plugin` dependency on the plugin in another build.

You may want to read about the new feature of sbt 0.13.5 - [auto plugins](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Using-Plugins.html#Enabling+and+disabling+auto+plugins) - that further ease setting up the plugin of yours:

> As of sbt 0.13.5, there is a new auto plugins feature that enables
>   plugins to automatically, and safely, ensure their settings and
>   dependencies are on a project.

Comment: Thanks. How can I refer to this in my project code now? I want to be able to access the value I assigned to `myConfigUrl` in one of my `.scala` files, not related to the build process.

Comment: I'm particularly interested in a way to let end users of `my-cool-plugin` define their own `myConfigUrl` which will be used instead of the default one in `my-cool-plugin`'s `build.sbt`.

Comment: See my updates to the answer. You will have to elaborate on *"not related to the build process."* a little bit to offer a more complete answer, though.

Comment: The answer should be complete now. I think autoplugins let you do more than you may have expected - let the beauty and power of sbt be with you! :)

Comment: Thanks, I definitely needed the `build.scala` example. I figured it out - defined the setting in an object in my `Plugin.scala` and now it can be overridden by importing that object and overriding the setting (like `MyCoolPlugin.settings ++ Seq( myConfigUrl := "http://myclientscoolwebsite.com/config.xml" )`.)

Comment: If it's about `*.sbt` files, you don't need to *"import that object"* since plugin objects are imported by default. Use `consoleProject` to learn what's going to be included in `*.sbt` files - the imports are printed out at startup.